# Linking List Web Parts Using CSOM

Tags: csom

I'm looking at linking 2 list webparts on a page. I have found code that suggests it is possible on the server side object model here.

http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/01/22/sharepoint-add-webpart-connection-programmatically/

I have not been able to find anything for the CSOM that does this, is it even possible?

Thanks.